# Como retornar um ponteiro para uma String, alocada dinamicamente, declarada dentro de uma função?

Tags: c, string, funções, alocação, malloc

```
//Função de inversão de String.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 30

char* invertStr(char *source)
{   
    int size = strlen(source);
    
    char *inverted = malloc(sizeof(source) * (size + 1));

    int count = size;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        inverted[i] = source[count];
        count--;
    }
    inverted[size + 1] = ('\0');

    return inverted;
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[SIZE];
    char str2[SIZE];

    scanf("%29s", str);

    char *inverted = invertStr(str);

    if (inverted == 0)
    {
        printf("NULL Pointer. Memory alocation error");

        return -1;
    }

    strcpy(str2, inverted);

    printf("%s | %s\n", str, str2);

    free(inverted);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

A saída da segunda string não é exibida com sucesso.

Código rodando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/N7K3NT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Tá alocando espaço demais. `sizeof(source)` é diferente do tamanho de `sizeof(*source)`.
2. Tá começando a escrever em cima do `\0` =>  `count = size - 1;`
3. Tá escrevendo o `\0` fora do limite alocado => `inverted[size] = '\0';`

```
char* invertStr(char *source)
{   
    int size = strlen(source);
    
    char *inverted = malloc(sizeof(*source) * (size + 1));

    int count = size - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        inverted[i] = source[count];
        count--;
    }
    inverted[size] = '\0';

    return inverted;
}
```

Comment: Mesmo assim está alocando espaço demais. Creio que deva ser: `char *inverted = malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1));`

Comment: @anonimo Não vejo diferença... `*source == char`. `source` é um ponteiro, vai ter 4 ou 8 bytes dependendo da arquitetura, `*source` é o que `source` aponta, que nesse caso é um `char`

Comment: O tipo `char` ocupa 1 byte, e um ponteiro - como você mesmo disse - ocupa 4 ou 8 bytes.

Comment: @anonimo `source` é um ponteiro. `*source` é um char.

Comment: @anonimo `sizeof(char)` e `sizeof(*source)`são equivalentes. Obrigado pela contribuição, gente. Zero Based Arrays + Null Terminator me confundem bastante, preciso praticar mais, além de entender melhor o funcionamento e os operandos de `sizeof`